# Back button doesn't show up on Honeycomb but does on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-theme

I am using the ActionBar in an app that has a menu in the top right and supposed to have the back button in the top left.  I have two Xoom tablets: one running Honeycomb and the other running ICS.  The ICS tablet correctly shows the back button in the top left and the honeycomb tablet does not.  Any suggestions?

I have a feeling that it could be a theme issue.  I have two separate theme.xml files: one for honeycomb and one for ICS.

Honeycomb theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="custom_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/content_direct_theme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/logowithbackarrow</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeInverse</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
    </style>
    <style name="custom_alert_dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly</item>
    </style>
    <style name="custom_theme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dark_gradient</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

ICS theme.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="custom_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>
    <style name="custom_dialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryDisableOnly</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Note: I couldn't use the Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme for Honeycomb because the text looked weird.